# Как резервируются vps в дата центрах

Tags: vps

Как компании, предлагающие услуги VPS, работают с отказоустойчивостью? Только не жестких дисков, а например, если полетит материнская плата.

К примеру, у меня есть сервер, на нем 10 контейнеров, каждый контейнер у меня как VPS, им кто-то пользуется. Как делают так, что если полетит материнская плата, блок питания или еще что, всё продолжало бы работать? Хотя бы на уровне идеи.

Comment: Кроме резервного копирования вы не придумаете ничего. Но тогда вылазит [CAP теорема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_CAP). И тогда из CAP каждый выбирает две буквы